# Show nearest locations(market, bus stand etc) of the search result(s) on Gmap Drupal 6

Tags: views, location, google-maps

I am using **view(style:map)** to show **search result on Gmap**. It works fine but i need to **show nearest locations(market, bus stand etc)** of the search result(s). How do I do that?

it is fine if I will get nearest locations(market, bus stand etc) on the search result(s) **by clicking a button or something else**. Please help.